# Avoinding duplicate ranks with PROC RANK

Tags: sas

I would like to use `PROC RANK` to rank multiple variables.  For simplicity the code below only demonstrates using a single variable.

In the case of a tie, I would like proc rank to just iterate across the next rank values.  The example code I give below gives the duplicate values (`333`) ranks of `3.5` and `3.5`.  I would like it to just assign `3` and `4` instead.

Is there a way to do this using `PROC RANK`?  I can fix it in a data step but if I can do it within the proc then that will keep things neater.

```
data have;
  input x;
  datalines;
100
200
333
333
;
run;

proc rank data=have out=dont_want;
  var x;
  ranks x_rank;
run;
```

Comment: I'm quite (not entirely) sure that this is not possible using Proc Rank.

Comment: Agreed, not sure this is possible within PROC RANK.

Comment: QUOTE: When PROC RANK ranks values, if two or more values of an analysis variable that are within a BY group are equal, then tied values are present in the data. Because the values are indistinguishable and there is usually no further obvious information on which the ranks can reasonably be based, PROC RANK does not assign different ranks to the values. See https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146844.htm#a003280358

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off with a data step if you need to consistently increase the rank.

```
proc sort data=have;
    by x;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    rank+1;
run;
```

If you have many variables to rank, you can use this macro below:

```
%macro sequential_rank(lib=, dsn=, out=);

    data want;
        set have;
    run;

    proc sql noprint;
        select name
        into :vars separated by '|'
        from dictionary.columns
        where     memname = %upcase("&dsn.")
              AND libname = %upcase("&lib.")
              AND type    = 'num'
        ;
    quit;

    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&vars., |));
        %let var = %scan(&vars., &i., |);

        proc sort data=&out.;
            by &var.;
        run;

        data &out.;
            set &out.;
            by &var.;

            rank_&var.+1;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
%sequential_rank(lib=work, dsn=have, out=want);
```

Comment: Seems like this is the answer unfortunately.  I have quite a lot of columns so I'll need to sort the dataset many times.  Was hoping to use proc rank to simplify but oh well...

Comment: I added a macro that will rank every numeric variable in a loop. You can modify this to specify only variables of interest if needed. I tried simplifying this with `proc ds2` but kept running into issues with overwriting the same dataset it's reading.

Comment: Do the many variables have similar names?

Comment: All of the variables are prefixed with `rank_`. E.g. the rank for `var1` is `rank_var1`. Try running it on `sashelp.cars` to see how it works.